# Converting external JS & CSS into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to combine an external JS file & CSS file into 1 HTML file by putting them internally in the HTML. The CSS is working fine with the style tag but not the JS file.

What should I change over here to link them up together?

Here is the external js file I got online:

```
    <script>

    function variables(){
        var btn_start = document.getElementById("start");
        var btn_reset = document.getElementById("reset");
        var btn_check = document.getElementById("check");

        var main_div = document.getElementById("main-div");

        var guess_box = document.getElementById("guess-box");
        var all_guesses = document.getElementById("all-guesses");
        var high_or_low = document.getElementById("high-or-low");

        var random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

        var count_guess = 1;
    }
    
    function start() {
        main_div.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function checkGuess() {
        var your_guess = Number(guess_box.value);

        if (count_guess <= 10) {
            if (your_guess < random_num) {
                all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
                high_or_low.textContent = "Your Guess is Low";
                high_or_low.classList.add("wrong");
                count_guess++;
                guess_box.value = '';
            }
            else if (your_guess > random_num) {
                all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
                high_or_low.textContent = "Your Guess is High";
                high_or_low.classList.add("wrong");
                count_guess++;
                guess_box.value = '';
            }
            else {
                all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
                high_or_low.textContent = "Congratulations! You Guessed it Right.";
                high_or_low.classList.add("success");
                guess_box.value = '';
                gameOver();
            }
        }
        else {
            all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
            high_or_low.textContent = "Game Over! Sorry, your chances are over.";
            high_or_low.classList.add("wrong");
            guess_box.value = '';
            gameOver();
        }
    }

    function gameOver() {
        btn_check.disabled = true;
        guess_box.disabled = true;
    }

</script>
```

Here is the the body:

```
<body>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script> // <--What should I change here
</body>
```

Comment: Remove the Script tag from JS file and it will work

Comment: What is the problem besides "does not work"? How does it not work? What console errors do you get? What doesn't happen that should? What does happen that shouldn't? Consider providing a [MCVE]. Also why do you want to do this. The Best Practice is to keep HTML / CSS and JS seperate

Comment: This question does not make sense. you say you have an external js file, but the contents you show would never work as an external js file, because it has `<script>` and `</script>`, which are only used when including script in HTML. So if you want to include it in HTML, just copy the entire file and paste it into your HTML file. It's not going to work, because you have none of the element the script refers to, but that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

In js file, remove `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your question to mean that you're trying to include the JS from the external file inline in your HTML wrapped in `<script>` tags.

If that's right, make sure you include the script **after** any DOM elements you're assigning to variables and referencing in the JS, or at least make sure that `variables()` is called after those elements in the DOM.

If your script occurs before those elements in the DOM, it will fail because it is executed and will look for elements that haven't been constructed yet.

Also, the way your variables are scoped, the functions have no access to the variables like `guess_box`, `main_div` etc. so they will do nothing...

`variables()` needn't be a function anyway -- if you take the function wrapper off it and just assign the variables above the other function statements, the code will work because the functions all have access to the variables in their parent scope. Consider wrapping the code in an IIFE so you're avoiding creating global variables.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
<!-- head stuff -->
</head>

<body>

<!-- end-user visible DOM elements here before JS -->

<script>
(function (){
  
  var btn_start = document.getElementById("start");
  var btn_reset = document.getElementById("reset");
  var btn_check = document.getElementById("check");

  var main_div = document.getElementById("main-div");

  var guess_box = document.getElementById("guess-box");
  var all_guesses = document.getElementById("all-guesses");
  var high_or_low = document.getElementById("high-or-low");

  var random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  var count_guess = 1;
    
  function start() {
    main_div.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  function checkGuess() {
    var your_guess = Number(guess_box.value);

    if (count_guess <= 10) {
      if (your_guess < random_num) {
        all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
        high_or_low.textContent = "Your Guess is Low";
        high_or_low.classList.add("wrong");
        count_guess++;
        guess_box.value = '';
      }
      else if (your_guess > random_num) {
        all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
        high_or_low.textContent = "Your Guess is High";
        high_or_low.classList.add("wrong");
        count_guess++;
        guess_box.value = '';
      }
      else {
        all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
        high_or_low.textContent = "Congratulations! You Guessed it Right.";
        high_or_low.classList.add("success");
        guess_box.value = '';
        gameOver();
      }
    }
    else {
      all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
      high_or_low.textContent = "Game Over! Sorry, your chances are over.";
      high_or_low.classList.add("wrong");
      guess_box.value = '';
      gameOver();
    }
  }

  function gameOver() {
      btn_check.disabled = true;
      guess_box.disabled = true;
  }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, since you have indicated in a comment that you'd like to include the JS in the `head` element, you can use an event listener to execute the code once the DOM is loaded, like so:

```
<head>
<script>
/* 
  this tells the browser to run the init() function 
  only when the webpage has been parsed by the browser 
  i.e. when all the elements 'exist'
*/
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

/*
  we wrap all the variable assignments and game logic in a function
  we can assign to handle an event, specifically the event above,
  'DOMContentLoaded'
*/
function init (){
  var btn_start = document.getElementById("start");
  var btn_reset = document.getElementById("reset");
  var btn_check = document.getElementById("check");

  var main_div = document.getElementById("main-div");

  var guess_box = document.getElementById("guess-box");
  var all_guesses = document.getElementById("all-guesses");
  var high_or_low = document.getElementById("high-or-low");

  var random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  var count_guess = 1;

  /*
    if the start() function needs to run automatically, 
    rather than being triggered by a user interaction (button being
    pushed etc), just run it in this init() event handler 
    function we're wrapping the function declaration in:
  */
  start();
    
  function start() {
    main_div.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  function checkGuess() {
    var your_guess = Number(guess_box.value);

    if (count_guess <= 10) {
      if (your_guess < random_num) {
        all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
        high_or_low.textContent = "Your Guess is Low";
        high_or_low.classList.add("wrong");
        count_guess++;
        guess_box.value = '';
      }
      else if (your_guess > random_num) {
        all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
        high_or_low.textContent = "Your Guess is High";
        high_or_low.classList.add("wrong");
        count_guess++;
        guess_box.value = '';
      }
      else {
        all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
        high_or_low.textContent = "Congratulations! You Guessed it Right.";
        high_or_low.classList.add("success");
        guess_box.value = '';
        gameOver();
      }
    }
    else {
      all_guesses.textContent += your_guess + " ";
      high_or_low.textContent = "Game Over! Sorry, your chances are over.";
      high_or_low.classList.add("wrong");
      guess_box.value = '';
      gameOver();
    }
  }

  function gameOver() {
      btn_check.disabled = true;
      guess_box.disabled = true;
  }

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- stuff -->
```

Wrapping all your stuff in a function and having that function execute when your web page actually being parsed by the browser using an event listener is another way to do what putting all your JS after the elements in the body does.

Comment: is it possible to put these codes in the <head> of js instead of within the <body>?

Comment: You can put the JS wherever you like, as long as the DOM elements your code manipulates are parsed before you execute the JS. So, for example, I suggest to include the JS after everything else at the end of the body element for simplicity -- you could alternatively put the JS in the head as a function and call that function with an event listener like `'DOMContentLoaded'`

Comment: I've added to my answer to explain what I mean @xxxxxalice